# How to change a value of a element in binary tree?

Tags: c, binary-tree

I made a binary and I want to change the value of some of it elements.

`ip_adresa` is the current IP address

`s_red_br` and `red_br` is the number of the PC

`s_ip_adresa` is the new ip adress that I need to give to some PC`s

UPDATE :

I fixid the function and the gcc doesnt shows any eror.But in the out-file the ip adress`s of the pc arent changed they are same.....

`

```
void update(FILE *upd, FILE *out, RACUNAR *root){
    int s_red_br;   
    char s_ip_adresa[MAX_IP];
    while(fscanf(upd, "%d %s", &s_red_br, s_ip_adresa) == 2){
         int temp = root->red_br;   
            char temp1 = *root->ip_adresa;                  
            if ( temp == s_red_br){
                temp1 = *s_ip_adresa;
                }
    }
}  `
```

RACUNAR is:
`

```
typedef struct racunar_st {
    int red_br;
    char naziv[MAX_NAZIV];
    char ip_adresa[MAX_IP];
    int brzina;
    struct racunar_st *left;
    struct racunar_st *right;
} RACUNAR;
```

Comment: I am not. Just want to find out where i am making a mistake.

Comment: `!=EOF` -> Perhaps `== 2` would be better

Comment: Ahhh sorry for that, it was on purpose.

Comment: A okay will change it ,its a habbit of mine to put EOF.

Comment: its a typedef struct

Comment: Please put that into the question? You can edit the question. But do not edit it in such a way that comments/answers do not make any sense. Just put it onto the end of the question

Comment: done, its in the question now.

Comment: This `temp != s_red_br` does not make any sense comparing an `int` with a `struct`

Comment: I know i get that that error in gcc.I dont know how to compare the pc number from a tree to a pc number that i load from a file.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
RACUNAR temp = root->red_br;
```

to

```
int temp = root->red_br;
```

Comment: I update my funcion but still it doesnt work.But now i dont get error from gcc.

Comment: It scans from the file,with our a problem, but when i want to compere them it doesnt do what it suppose to do...